# staging image on facebook with javascript to compose a custom object

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, staging

I'm reading this interesting part of FB:
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api#objectapi-images]

My goal is to sent a custom object to graph api explorer, completed of a staged image.

Please have a look to the FB documentation, paragraph about **staging images**.

I want to stage the image, get it later, and then **compose an object with the staged image** and push it to the graph api as a **story**.

There is only one example in CURL.
I would like to use FB.api().

I've been trying to do something like:

```
 FB.api(
       'https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources',
       'post',
       {'file' : '@images/prawn-curry-1.jpg',
       'access_token' : $USER_ACCESS_TOKEN},
       function(response) {
         if (!response) {
           alert('Error occurred.');
         } else if (response.error) {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
             'Error: ' + response.error.message;
         } else {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
             '<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/' +
             response.id + '\">' +
             'Story created.  ID is ' +
             response.id + '</a>';
         }
       }
    );
```

but it does not like it, although the access_token is the appID.
I thought the access_token will be held in request and tried:

```
 FB.api(
       'https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources',
       'post',
       {'file' : '@images/prawn-curry-1.jpg'},
       function(response) {
         if (!response) {
           alert('Error occurred.');
         } else if (response.error) {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
             'Error: ' + response.error.message;
         } else {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
             '<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/' +
             response.id + '\">' +
             'Story created.  ID is ' +
             response.id + '</a>';
         }
       }
    );
```

but it does not take the image, neither with an absolute url.
(I guess the syntax @images/ means a relative url to the path, I've never seen it in this context).

- Could you please tell me what is wrong here for staging an image with
  javascript?
- Can I post an image in Base64 or is the protocol the same
  of /graph/me/photo? api ? I am trying to upload from canvas :)
- Can you clarify how to call the image and compose the object story? It is not clear if the staged image will only be present *temporarily*, so to update the same object, or I can store indefinite objects, so that I should take care of naming.

In the link above, it looks like it query by image filename, and it is not clear to me if I can fetch *by ID * (exact matching) after response is successful so to upload a custom object, completed of its own image, to the graph api explorer.

Comment: `@local_path/filename.ext` is a special cURL syntax to pass a file that should be uploaded like a file upload via an HTML form would; you can not just take that and put it into a totally different context, and expect it to work. // I am not sure if the JS SDK supports that kind of upload at all; you might need to build it yourself instead. (The `FormData` object might be a good starting point for that.)

Comment: Hi @CBroe, do you mean that Facebook JS SDK does not support the operation of staging an image?

Comment: It does not offer a possibility to upload local images built-in.

Comment: I am trying with `FormData` object: E.g. this a piece of code I am re-using that post a built-in local image to *FB photos*: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + authToken, true );
    xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log( xhr.responseText );
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary );
    xhr.sendAsBinary( formData );`
Instead of `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos`, I want to do it against graph explorer API, so to stage the image first.

Comment: Should work pretty much the same way.

Comment: I tried replacing endingpoint: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos` with `https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources`.
As a result I had an `Uri` created here: `fbstaging://graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/MDExMDIwODE2ODU0NjE5NjQ0MzoxODMxMTQzOTg=` but it is empty.
POST on FB reply with an error: `"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (staging_resources) on node type (User)"`. It is not clear to me though: am I correct that FB indicates stage resources as a field of user like with this syntax `https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97281/discussion-between-user305883-and-cbroe).